# How to set an auto scale for text number in Vega-Lite

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I have a Vega-Lite chart built in a Power BI report that is underpinned by a dimensional model. The report offers users the ability to drill down into categories and I would like for the chart to display the text marks based on the scale of the number.

Unfortunately I cannot share the report but can offer this  [mock up](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAGI1ZSWVBo6ABAE04SAE5oATAAY3AZiUBpAAUASVsAOSQEODQQULl+ACU4WTgAdyQmQX1FEABVCCQyOFsAYXs0AE4ADkoxNzclPIKigLLUSuqxMQA2JQAVF0LMNEq3SgB2bqUA5zZlBihMdlkS1rExgBYxjymZuYWl2xa0bw8uzwBfBVNzS2s7Rxd3L18QQJDwyOjE5LSMrIb8oUVscAIyULogyoApqHVrearldb1ED9ZyDY5dSjecrI6azeaLOTA1BrTbbEB4vaE5ZHVBuMYgraUSrnAC6lxAmGclggADM2M4EEZQFAdFAGII1FF0ABySkEg7FBjOZxJTC2Ez2GXZJAGdDy-ZE0q2AAy5CSyhAlxFYolUuict2CqJ03Yzg1Wp1eopTsNNPspvNskt1pAosE4slmGlIBlAFFMgtnDRrJgAJ62VGDbVKXXRLNwdVmwrBq1XMO2qMx1SYBgIQwyt5hCJwGWs2wAalsMsOyYFHpzIDz6GKUrIArTR1D4cj9vQNbrDabH1b7a7PaVKrVA690VH0fHzjTpStrKU8BoZCwxw85JSNGU9Bv5Kgcl5l7QoEyJctmhAApoNVoiYNhsDYIUlElJg4EEEw5EwABlGgAC9pShMM2F0BBZD1ZFJTTNgGCGP8QLAoU-1uGABWiBAH2UTIrXOJjIKQNM4FcVBjBAfD2OFEALE+dAEzgJMUzoDMTyUZBnAAa0-Tk0xwGMmEeJQAA8AHleV5CBCzQckIBQ6UTiUTA2EwxYcDQLk9A5JJX2UcwyHktT5PfGDfxAMwLCsGxBAcJxXFMxSYwFRyLEEHU1JoPUv3SGCAEFZDIBjUA8DkZGcYjZAlQQOTTNzAMETzGiBSSFKU6IAEcGEsRZ1EWUhsnq1KQGE0TUwzIJZGjHDxNsAAKGSAHUYFsAhbDMmlfWpABKMsMMEai-3c4q9zHCdyvTSr0FkcCbkipRoB0aVQGUcCkHMIwQG+VJ0kyCBezdD1slu34HpKZVVR6l6lFiWQEiSO6-ke11+01bJ-sBn57v0T6tx+iGzxAblkulQwQAAYnWdZyi6AAhYpskx7EEu8dZ8eJsQEuKSoTAS4n1mKAARPH1hAdlIKDX9QBamNGKUMLeJWorfwx-dyE2spkaFjiMd1KALScjmmNDASY3arkxPTWFsmkuS-225TVJATTtN04j+BMkBDNQm9TPMwRLOs5xbKUezZmVv9XJFjzom824-ICk2jeiMKDqimL5KgxLktS9KjoFbLcvywq-fQUrmjKYKdpAGq6roNQaCa3Nor1HLBDypRXyWjjQFWzyJcPSds4qmM9toiLsmO1Kzouq7OJuoH3rhsH3QhpQ3thx7N2+9UJ5iOIp5Bp7wdbqHl4+2ftyRpRUcKa7sdxgmiaUEnyjJimqZpumGbPpnWa6dnOe47n5L56IBf-ZxlGF+vReuk3CcRwZY-2FvLaAStkoq2YqAdW+YErxAAOJxl6HrFwBteYhWAibM2Ok9KoGtrbYyL5MLLSxiYEwxRii3mao7Z2qAbJwDslYT20DvZpzWugAOvl7iBWatg9A4cu6lyjn+GOggkopWlAnG2Sc0AVyriAAqFEyBkFVBQaM0QIB1myA3fMAw9I5xjPnHqhdGpRFEeXFOSh3yV04Z5AsRY35HXDKdFGlgD6D0xpQ6htCX7fgtO-OgrVGKwM5KjPkApyJcTsdGDiKg1CLhlJnFYbZbAAEIAC8thFGniUPAoSiYtadRWLYZmagkCmnioIAwUkMHv0EZyOAakhi5mEGQeQ6BkxXjaSAFSulhDJGiEMuA-BSJmQgioH2IIXj8h6khO2qAQRuBYQ5L2oAfb-3Tl5G4vD-IPCCm3MOP8I6Jyygomxyj5IFHUXwLR6AdFTP0RnQERQtpNNMfVIuJchxl0uZXDk0ZWk3LURoucNtdG2IAa8mEHzc5fPMcXSxIB+SCjUNESgIJeRhPLIUtqxTkylJaOUyp1ToK1PQbJRpudgV9J0JeLpKNLzXiUAMmC5gYyjPGaBSZ2RlA+34JCWx8FFnShWWsthzkOG+y4bsnydwDn8OMSc8KOhu7yNQIo1Oqi7maJjE8vRMLchvN1iq9AiKGrIsjtYwFpkWnEVALc8FDzIXPONako45q861TMVa35aLkDERAFinFqs8UtgQcg1B5KYJ1JAPrGlMY6U6g6UynprL+m6g5cM9A3KJngX5T7dYczRVGTQBK92rDwrSs2Q4-2ezFXByOaHIRpyRFyIuVqq5KinVgvuQaqFqLjVOIEQi313yLE2oBUolNuqXWDvdTs0d3rLU-JRYGjF6BQ1hORqqGQggmp-h7u4lRNsYAuDgCGKx8kz3mF-kpYMQFw1xTYnLV94C4GRv1DNRUrdE2GyadYZwUAGIOwsjQKyjDXbMKres9hdbZWeR4U2w5Y7QrtvVec5OdrrlIeiAaakwJV0TqRb8k98lUIzDQLyHQukgUhJjIRg4A0przRFei4NSgMpcjYDJdxLyfT4j9GU4sQTXEnXkvvdGWMuhyfkyrLmP5gmYFCarNW36hNUgOF6hNDTAO52A6BlFZkINQaYZKmtLl63cMbUHND3rhFYc7ThpRvahz9v1doodgnmMulbhRv8VG2A0bo7B45FrSP+pRUgf53bK4caDdEbjR1eP8Zs1p50-pAzKYk73DxaNrqqktAEt+htGOf3UxGwSmWRPGgqeoWNlL6nUoM8mh1qbGU0TomBrNgzOXRDMlZJQAq0D8E8CNlRQqxAioWeW5Zqy4NSus-h2zCr7PKoi9-NVh0XMzp1dsuVfnljwpMVF9d3c3GUfYiF1AtHanhdi2I7V9qQWrdq0R071VztTsS1u7IL7+KaeO7CUljWTQ1PjQBrBtKOvtK6+gWiyh6IovZaMwbbBhvTLGxNlQU2QQzdRWWpZlaQAeyszKw7yG7N8JDk0pzu3MquYOx5vVELDXQp2SD3TgXQDBdCw9oFnyfvWpvfF2dHX50Du80uo7v7-Poe+wXaLejon-e40xPd+hMJHqdXF0Ad6n2Pt-j1BavObZpZjPeuAxvn2a73trw97jzeG4fRaICqWZjpfQNb23pvVbsiAA).

The rule to be implemented is, if the number is greater than 10 000 then display as 10k else display as is. Ideally the number must be rendered with a thousand separator.

For example, with no filters applied:

[image: no filter applied]

With a category filtered:
[image: filter applied]

If this is possible, please would you share how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% clear on your rules but reading as written, I would just add a calculate to give you the label you want. You can use d3format (https://github.com/d3/d3-format/) or just add your own logic like this using a ternary operator.

{"calculate": "datum['Production CY'] > 10000?'10k':datum['Production CY'] ", "as": "label1"}

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Financial Year": 2023,
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "Usage CY": 98.522,
        "Usage PY": 88.556,
        "Target": 82.756,
        "Production CY": 57470,
        "Production PY": 30620
      },
      {
        "Financial Year": 2023,
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "Usage CY": 31.618,
        "Usage PY": 38.942,
        "Target": 36.392,
        "Production CY": 57470,
        "Production PY": 27170.8
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "'Production Current FY'", "as": "Production CY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Production Prior FY'", "as": "Production PY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Electricity Target'", "as": "Target Legend"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' Prior FY'", "as": "CategoryPY"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' Current FY'", "as": "CategoryCY"},
    {"calculate": "datum['Production CY'] > 10000?'10k':datum['Production CY'] ", "as": "label1"}
  ],
  "height": 300,
  "width": 300,
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "labelFontSize": 8,
      "columns": 2,
      "layout": {"bottom": {"anchor": "middle"}}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "name": "Electricity CY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": 0, "size": 30, "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Year",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0},
              "sort": null
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Electricity Intensity (kWh / ton Production)"
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryCY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Renewables Prior FY",
                  "Renewables Current FY",
                  "Non-Renewables Prior FY",
                  "Non-Renewables Current FY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#39A34B", "#5AC8FA", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            },
            "order": {"field": ["CategoryCY"], "order": ["ascending"]}
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Electricity PY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": -30, "size": 30, "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Year",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0},
              "sort": null
            },
            "y": {"field": "Usage PY", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryPY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Renewables Prior FY",
                  "Renewables Current FY",
                  "Non-Renewables Prior FY",
                  "Non-Renewables Current FY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#39A34B", "#5AC8FA", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            },
            "order": {"field": ["CategoryPY"], "order": ["ascending"]}
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TARGET",
          "mark": {
            "type": "bar",
            "xOffset": 30,
            "size": 30,
            "color": "#FFCC00",
            "tooltip": true
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Year",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0},
              "sort": null
            },
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "fill": {
              "field": "Target Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["#FFCC00"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [{"filter": "datum['Usage CY'] != null"}],
          "name": "Electricity CY Data Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": 13,
            "fontSize": 12
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Year", "type": "ordinal", "sort": null},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ".1f"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Electricity PY Data Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": -18,
            "fontSize": 12
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Year", "type": "ordinal", "sort": null},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ".1f"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TARGET Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": 43,
            "fontSize": 12
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Year", "type": "ordinal", "sort": null},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ".1f"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "shared"}, "axis": {"y": "independent"}}
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "layer": [
            {
              "name": "Production CY",
              "mark": {"type": "circle", "tooltip": true},
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "Financial Year",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "sort": null
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "Production CY",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "scale": {"zero": false},
                  "title": "Production (ton)",
                  "format": ","
                },
                "stroke": {
                  "field": "Production CY Legend",
                  "scale": {"range": ["#666666"]},
                  "legend": {"title": ""}
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "Production PY",
              "mark": {"type": "circle", "tooltip": true},
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "Financial Year",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "sort": null
                },
                "y": {
                  "aggregate": "sum",
                  "field": "Production PY",
                  "scale": {"zero": false},
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "axis": null,
                  "format": ","
                },
                "stroke": {
                  "field": "Production PY Legend",
                  "scale": {"range": ["red"]},
                  "legend": {"title": ""}
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "Production CY Data Labels",
              "mark": {
                "type": "text",
                "align": "middle",
                "baseline": "top",
                "dx": -20,
                "dy": -15,
                "fontSize": 12
              },
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "Financial Year",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "sort": null
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "Production CY",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "scale": {"zero": false},
                  "axis": null
                },
                "text": {
                  "field": "label1"
                  
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "Production PY Data Labels",
              "mark": {
                "type": "text",
                "align": "middle",
                "baseline": "top",
                "dx": -20,
                "dy": -15,
                "fontSize": 12
              },
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "Financial Year",
                  "type": "ordinal",
                  "sort": null
                },
                "y": {
                  "aggregate": "sum",
                  "field": "Production PY",
                  "scale": {"zero": false},
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "axis": null
                },
                "text": {
                  "aggregate": "sum",
                  "field": "Production PY",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "format": ","
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "resolve": {
            "axis": {"y": "independent"},
            "scale": {"stroke": "independent"}
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent", "stroke": "independent"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you David. Apologies, in retrospect I could have phrased this better. But this is enough to get me going. Thanks again.